# Make JFileChooser start in a folder inside its own .jar

Tags: jar, directory, executable-jar, jfilechooser

I have a program that I pack into a .jar archive. At the top level in the archive I have the main class and a folder called images. How can I make a `JFileChooser` start in the image folder inside the .jar archive?

If I use `JFileChooser open = new JFileChooser("images");` it will start in a folder called images OUTSIDE the archive, but thats not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFileChooser works with filesystem, it does not treat jar/zip files as filesystem.

You need to implement your own class to navigate your jar-file.

Consider [Apache VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/) project.